# R fuzzyjoin in python

Tags: python, pandas

`fuzzyjoin` is an R library that allows to do joins based on functions, instead of equality of ids. I am wondering if the same thing can be done in Python. For instance, I might want to do a join based on two inequalities. I have the following DataFrames:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    x=range(10)
))

other_df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    min_x=[0, 6],
    max_x=[5, 10],
    category=['a', 'b']
))
```

And I want to left join `df` and `other_df` such that `x >= min_x` and `x <= max_x`, obtaining the following dataframe:

```
   x category
0  0        a
1  1        a
2  2        a
3  3        a
4  4        a
5  5        a
6  6        b
7  7        b
8  8        b
9  9        b
```

Is there an easy way to do this in pandas?

Comment: just making sure that your expected output is not wrong, but I don't think that x = 5 can have category = b since the min_x for b is 6

Comment: you're right, changed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible to do the same in python. It can be done in the following manner -

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    x=range(10)
))

other_df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    min_x=[0, 6],
    max_x=[5, 10],
    category=['a', 'b']
))

df['category'] = df['x'].apply(lambda x: other_df.loc[(other_df['min_x'] <= x) & (other_df['max_x'] >= x), 'category'].item())

print(df)
```

I have used the pandas `apply` to execute the same function (in this case its a lambda function) on every item in a column. In that apply function I have executed the `loc` function to lookup values based on conditionals from your `other_df` and have used those values to build a new column.

Answer (score 0):

One efficient option is with [janitor.conditional_join](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.conditional_join.conditional_join):

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import janitor 
import pandas as pd
(df
.conditional_join(
    other_df, 
    ('x', 'min_x', '>='), 
    ('x', 'max_x', '<='), 
    right_columns = 'category')
) 
   x category
0  0        a
1  1        a
2  2        a
3  3        a
4  4        a
5  5        a
6  6        b
7  7        b
8  8        b
9  9        b
```

Since there is no overlaps in the ranges for `other_df`, [pd.merge_asof](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html) suffices:

```py
(pd
.merge_asof(
    df, 
    other_df, 
    left_on = 'x', 
    right_on = 'min_x')
.loc(axis=1)[['x', 'category']]
)
0  0        a
1  1        a
2  2        a
3  3        a
4  4        a
5  5        a
6  6        b
7  7        b
8  8        b
9  9        b
```